# Is there a way to include multiple javascript files in a django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, minify, django-template-filters

Write now in my Django template I have something that looks like this with like 10 files:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "/js/main_1.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "/js/main_2.js" %}"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "/js/main_3.js" %}"></script>`

What I was wondering was if there was a way to do:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static ["/js/main_1.js","/js/main_2.js","/js/main_3.js"] %}"></script>`

and then have python have a minified version of all them.

Comment: put them all in one js file.

Comment: @almostabeginner putting them all in one file would be tricky because it would make them hard to edit.  Also some of the files are controlled by npm and updated automatically.  Putting them all in one file would break that.

Comment: if you are 'minifying' (if that is even a word), then it is recommended to combine all your js files in order to reduce the number of requests. I understand what you're trying to do, but it is beyond me as I'm still a beginner. Keep us updated if you do find a solution, it would be good to learn. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a great way to combine when you are linking the scripts in your template. You can write a script that will generate URLs for you, but unless the number is unmanageable I wouldn't recommend that. 10 is not so many.

For the minifying I would use [Django Compressor](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor). It will take your linked javascript and turn them into minified, cacheable files automatically.